# How do I record in VLC media player on a schedule?

Tags: vlc-media-player, shell-script, recording, vbscript, autoit

I have an IP stream coming through VLC media player in Window 7, and I would like to automate the process of opening the stream and start recording at a specified time, and stop VLC and the recording at a specified time.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done.  Since your using Windows I'd recommend looking into the Windows Event Scheduler.  Official Microsoft documentation can be found [HERE](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7).

Since you don't provide any details about where the stream is coming from I can only give you general guidance.  But it's going to look something like this.

1. Setup Windows Event Scheduler to run a batch script when you want the stream to open and start recording.
2. Create a batch script that opens the IP stream, and starts recording.

The script is going to look something like this:

```
 "C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe http://host[:port]/url" "#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=400,fps=5,scale=1,width=1024,height=768,acodec=none}:duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=mp4,dst='C:/capture223.mp4'}}"
```

This is extremely rough and will require lots of tweaking for it to work.  I'd recommend reading the command line help [HERE.](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help)